# Change a particular object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Starting with an array of objects:

```
var array=[
    {name:"name1",value:"value1"},
    {name:"nameToChange",value:"oldValue"},
    {name:"name3",value:"value3"}
];
```

How do change the value of a given property of one of the objects when another given property in the object is set to a given value?

For instance, starting with my array shown above, I wish to change `value` to "newValue" when `name` is equal to "nameToChange".

```
var array=[
    {name:"name1",value:"value1"},
    {name:"nameToChange",value:"newValue"},
    {name:"name3",value:"value3"}
];
```

PS.  To create the initial array, I am using jQuery's `serializeArray()`, and I do not wish to change the value of `<input name="nameToChange">`.  I suppose I can change its value, use `serialArray()`, and then change it back, but this sounds more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Is it reading a property on an object? Setting a property's new value? Finding the right object in the Array? How to perform an action based on a condition? This is all JavaScript 101 stuff.

Comment: @BlueSkies.  I can do it by manually looping through the array.  Didn't know if there is a simpler or more semantically correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through all the elements and search for the required one and then replace with the value.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i]["name"] == str) {
        array[i]["value"] = newValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will select this answer.  Probably slightly faster, however, to iterate backwards through the array?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to iterate over this array:

```
var i = arr.length;
while (i--) {
  if (arr[i].name === 'nameToChange') {
    arr[i].value = 'newValue';
    break; 
  } 
}
```

You won't be able to do the same stuff with native 'indexOf', as objects are to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].name == 'nameToChange') {
        array[i].value = 'value';
        break;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x6LCM/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It's 2013; skip all the messy `for` loops and use `forEach`. It's much simpler and semantically cleaner:

```
array.forEach(function (e) {
  if (e.name == 'nameToChange')
    e.value = 'newValue';
})
```

Comment: 'There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop.' And while I agree that `forEach` is far better replacement when you indeed need to something for _each_ element of an array, I don't agree this is the case.

Comment: @raina77ow  What about `return false;`?

Comment: `forEach` ignores the return value of the callback.

Comment: If you really need to break early, use `.some` or `.every` instead of `.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you could use this:

```
$.each(array, function () {
    if(this.name == 'nameToChange') this.value = 'value';
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrA59/)

Comment: A) that's a jQuery solution which is totally unnecessary and B) that's not at all a correct use of `map`; there's a ton of unnecessary overhead for such a misuse.

Comment: @meagar, I meant `each`... saw your answer with plain JS, sure, plain JS is always better, but this is not wrong.

Comment: It was inarguable wrong, when it was using `map`, and I'd argue it's *still* wrong now. Using jQuery this way makes it a crutch.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should use the generic iterator `$.each(array, func...)`

Comment: @BlueSkies, that is a good point! Changed. Other answers refer vanilla JS so I leave this here with jQuery.